# (麻薯), what kind, if not then what is it?

Tags: translation, word-requests

Someone translated this 麻薯 as a "potato" and Google Translate says it's Mochi, If it is a potato, could anyone share what kind?

When I tried some research I came up with what looks like a character website (http://taiwanmochi.com.tw).

In English we have sweet potato, red, white, and other kinds...

Google Translate (which I am learning is not reliable) shows this for potato.

> Translations of potato
>   noun:
>   马铃薯
>   potato
>   土豆
>   potato, spud
>   薯
>   potato, yam

Comment: In the Doraemon comic, it should be mochi, not potato.

Comment: @AngelLeliel Thanks for the info: I'm a bit confused because in the comic this is the answer in response to "What is this (while looking at food)?", is there some word play (double-meaning) going on between the characters?

Comment: More precisely, it should be "yakimochi", i.e. "roasted rice cake". You may search Google for more images.

Comment: I don't think so. Doraemon is from the future and he doesn't known many things at the present time.

Comment: 麻薯 in Taiwanese Hokkien is pronounced as [moa-chi], which, compared to Mandarin Chinese, is more similar to Japanese pronunciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

麻薯 or 麻糬 is the transcription of Japanese desert "[Mochi/もち](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mochi)".

The character 薯 means root vegetables.
Most of time it will be potato.

Some examples:

馬鈴薯 potato
蕃薯 sweet potato
木薯/樹薯 cassava